# Expected value of absolute equal to absolute of expected value?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, random-variables, absolute-value, expected-value

I have a following two function:

$a = \mathbb{E}_x\left[\left|{\bf f}(x)^H{\bf g} \right|\right]$ and $b = \left|\mathbb{E}_x\left[{\bf f}(x) \right]^H {\bf g} \right|$, where $H$ stands for conjugate transpose operation, $x$ is a uniformly distributed random variable. Other variables are such that ${\bf f}(x) \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ (${\bf f}$ is a function of $x$ defined as ${\bf f} = \left[e^{j\pi\cos(x)}, e^{j2\pi\cos(x)}, \dots, e^{j N\pi\cos(x)} \right]^T$) and ${\bf g} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$.

Is $a$ is equivalent to $b$ and if yes then can someone kindly suggest how to proceed to prove it?

Comment: What does superscript $H$ mean? You have not shown your attempt but you have used the tag 'proof-verification'. What does $a$ equivalent to $b$ mean?

Comment: I am stuck at how to proceed for the proof. But I am not also sure if a is equivalent to b. By 'equivalent' , I mean if they have equal expected value.

Answer (score 0):

For a centered uniform variable, by symmetry, the expectation is zero, while the expectation of the absolute value is positive.

Comment: I did not get the Gaussian reference. The random variable, in this case, is $x$ which is a uniformly distributed random variable.

Comment: @ChandanPradhan My bad. Same for a centered uniform distribution. For signed variables, $a\ne b$ in general.

Comment: The ${\bf f}$ here depends on the uniform random variable $x$. I am not sure that $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$ will be zero by symmetry.

Comment: @ChandanPradhan: for the last time, for signed variables $a\ne b$.